# how to use the hyperlink in dojo javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

Here is my code so far,

```
<html>
       <head>
    <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.1/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" />
      <script djConfig="parseOnLoad:true" type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js">
          </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dojo.parser");
            dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
            dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
                    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

        </script>
        </head>

    <body class="soria">
       <h1></h1>
          <br>



            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer"  style="width:880px;  height:500px; margin:15px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 1px;">

                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="HOME"></div>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" href="Franchise.html" title="FRANCHISE"></div>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="CAMPAIGN">
                          <b>Alice Kramden</b><br>VP Marketing
                  </div>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="STORES" >
                      <b>Trixie Norton</b><br>Treasurer
                  </div>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="GUESTS">
                          <b>Alice Kramden</b><br>VP Marketing
                  </div>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="REPORTING">
                          <b>Alice Kramden</b><br>VP Marketing
                  </div>

                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="USERS">
                          <b>Alice Kramden</b><br>VP Marketing
                  </div>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="ROLES">
                          <b>Alice Kramden</b><br>VP Marketing
                  </div>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="LOGOUT">
                          <b>Alice Kramden</b><br>VP Marketing
                  </div>
              </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am using href in `franchise tab`,i want to display my franchise page under franchise tab, actually i am able to see the div contains of franchise page but not able to see dojo tree i am using in franchise page what i can do

[here is my franchise page code](http://pastebin.com/hJDCyUfn)

Thanks You very much for coperation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but dijit.layout.ContentPane will not parse widgets for you, it just inlines HTML fragments.  You might look at using dojox.layout.ContentPane or calling dojo.parser to parse the content you add.  Also, you should consider using a recent version of Dojo.  The latest version is 1.7 (note that dojo.xd.js changes to dojo.js in this version for the CDN)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **parseOnLoad="true"** attribute so dojo translates any html elements with the **dojoType** attribute into its corresponding dojo widget